# How to left blank spaces inline?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to left several blank spaces in a table, but I'm not able to do it. But in the same table I'm able to do it when I don't use javascript.

For example, in this cell, I can left 4 blank spaces with `&nbsp;`

```
            <td>
                {props.tcs.tl_conv + " / " + props.tcs.tl_int}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                {(props.lang == "es") ? String(props.tcs.tl_percentage).replace(".", ",") + "%" : props.tcs.tl_percentage + "%"}
            </td>
```

But when previosuly I try to left 4 blank spaces with " ".repeat(4) or with "    ".

```
            <td>{
                (props.lang == "es") ? 
                    String(props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp).replace(".", ",") + " / " + String(props.tcs.t2p_int_pp).replace(".", ",") +  
                    " ".repeat(4) + String(props.tcs.t2p_percentage).replace(".", ",") + "%"     
                    : 
                    props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp + " / " + props.tcs.t2p_int_pp + " ".repeat(4) + props.tcs.t2p_percentage + "%"
                }
            </td>
```

How can I left blank spaces in this last piece of code?

Comment: You don't, you tag your content with a `<span className="...">` and then you use a CSS class that effects that white space. Also you _really_ want to be using template strings, instead of using all those `+` concatenations.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans some projects may not be able to use template strings due to compatibility issues.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a class, or style attribute with `white-space: pre;` or `white-space: pre-wrap` depending if you require wrapping or not

Comment: Hi @Rylee!!! It works!!! Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: @Rylee, if you're using React, you're almost certainly using webpack with babel. Which means you can use template strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a template string?  Template strings maintain their formatting.

```
`${props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp} / ${props.tcs.t2p_int_pp}    ${props.tcs.t2p_percentage}%`
                                    // spaces here ^^^^
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm not using jQuery, I'm using React.

Comment: Using syntax like ${variable} inside of backtick (`) characters is not jQuery.  It is native javascript that can be used to embed variables inside of strings.  It also happens to be that formatting inside a template string is maintained when rendered as html.  I highly recommend looking up [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) they're super handy!

Answer (score 0):

'\xa0' is no break space char, and if you add them in between you JS you should be able to get spaces without using the &nbsp.

**For example**

```
<td>{
       (props.lang == "es") ? 
       String(props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp).replace(".", ",") + " / " + 
       String(props.tcs.t2p_int_pp).replace(".", ",") +  
       '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0' + String(props.tcs.t2p_percentage).replace(".", ",") + "%":
       props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp + " / " + props.tcs.t2p_int_pp + " ".repeat(4) + 
       props.tcs.t2p_percentage + "%"
    }
</td>
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Trent Yetzer!!! You have understand me perfectly. Thanks for your appreciated help, but it doesn't work to me :( I have updated your post with the result.

Comment: @JoséCarlos, I used the wrong slash, it is supposed to be with a backslash, so instead it should be '\xa0' .
I will update my answer with the correct slash.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rylee I have found the solution. Finally, my piece of code is:

```
            <td>{
                (props.lang == "es") ? 
                    <span style = {{whiteSpace: "pre"}}>
                        {String(props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp).replace(".", ",") + " / " + String(props.tcs.t2p_int_pp).replace(".", ",") +  
                        "    " + String(props.tcs.t2p_percentage).replace(".", ",") + "%"}
                    </span>      
                    : 
                    props.tcs.t2p_conv_pp + " / " + props.tcs.t2p_int_pp + " ".repeat(4) + props.tcs.t2p_percentage + "%"
                }
            </td>
```

And here is the result:

[image]